# I want to verify that Rust compiler can call Visual Studio C++ Build tool properly with some simple code example

Tags: visual-studio, rust

New question: Could some one please give me some trivial code example to verify that Rust compiler can call Visual Studio C++ Build tool properly?

Original question:

I followed the instruction on the page of Rust site:

[You may need to install the Visual Studio C++ Build tools](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)

After finishing installation of the C build tools, though I failed to build a crate(Nannou) with the following error message:

```
VS code:
> cargo run --release --example draw
...
... 
Compiling examples v0.1.0 (O:\OneDrive\Git\IT\download\Rust\nannou-master\examples)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 7m 00s
     Running `target\release\examples\draw.exe`
thread 'main' panicked at 'could not build default app window: NoAvailableAdapter', O:\OneDrive\Git\IT\download\Rust\nannou-master\nannou\src\app.rs:457:18
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\release\examples\draw.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

I found that the path environment variable has not added for the installed C build tools. And I can't find where the C build tools are installed on my windows.
Please help me to setup the c build tools for Rust properly.

[Nannou crate](https://guide.nannou.cc/getting_started/running_examples.html)

Comment: It looks like your crate may be building, but is encountering a run-time error (`cargo run` builds and then executes the binary). What is the output of `cargo build --example draw`?

Comment: @PitaJ, it says as usual. I edited the question to include more detailed compiler error messages in terms of your comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. It's obvious that the compilation step is completing successfully, otherwise there would be no draw.exe

Comment: @PitaJ,Yes. But I still have a doubt  on that  C++ build tools not working properly. If I can test the C++ build  tools in Rust  with some simple code then I can clear the possibility.